# csh/tcsh How to find if a particular string is in a variable/filename?

Tags: string, shell, filenames, csh, tcsh

I want to check if a particular string is in a filename( which is a variable). [in csh/tcsh]

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set file = 'KZ.KKAR..BHZ.2008-01-18T19-16-51.SAC'
set string = 'BHZ'
echo $file
if [[$file == *$string*]];then
    echo 'string contains in this'
else 
    echo "NOOOOOOOOO"
endif
```

something like this.
Or
In a single line of code if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=~` to match against glob patterns:

```
if ( $file =~ *$string* ) then
```

Note that `[[..]]; then` is not valid (t)csh syntax; this only works for the Bourne shell.

This is documented in `man tcsh`:

> The '==' '!=' '=~' and '!~' operators compare their arguments as strings; all
> others operate on numbers.  The operators '=~' and '!~' are like '!=' and '=='
> except that the right hand side is a glob-pattern (see Filename substitution)
> against which the left hand operand is matched.  This reduces the need for use
> of the switch builtin command in shell scripts when all that is really needed
> is pattern matching.

As the documentation mentions, `switch` can also use glob patterns, similar to
the Bourne shell.